# Select specific element from set of MYSQL elements in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a Request table that has some columns. I need to select a row in the table and then use a specific column value(say request_initiator) to search it in another table.

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM Requests WHERE `request_id` = ?', req.body.id, function(error,results, fields){}
```

My `results` gives me multiple objects which then contains the component elements with different value.

```
0   
request_id  1
user_id "user1"
from    "owner1@xyz.com"
to  "owner2"
status  "deleted"
1   
request_id  2
user_id "user4"
from    "owner3@xyz.com"
to  "owner2"
status  "pending"
```

I have to access `results` to get `from` and then search it in `Owners` table.

However, `results.from` doesn't give anything. `results[0]` gives the first object but I can't access the elements of that list

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: `results[0].from`?

Comment: @TheMaster it gives undefined

Comment: Provide result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0]))`

Comment: {"Request_id":1,"user_id":"user1","from":"owner1@xyz.com","to":"owner2","status":"deleted"}

Comment: I don't get it. Then `results[0].from` should've worked. May be `console.log(results[0]["from"])`

Comment: Finally! It worked, thanks, reply this as the answer so I can select. I feel like it should have worked with results[0].from, but at least this workaround works.

Comment: Are you sure `results[0].from` didn't work?

Comment: Yep, I had tried it before asking the question as well, but it didn't. It gave undefined every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` is a array of multiple objects. You can access the `from` key's value using

```
results[0]["from"]
```